# Fix broken link of sub site

Tags: 2007, site-collection, sub-site

I am the admin for a SP2007 MOSS system which is based off of a root site collection at:
`https://publicsites/`

I recently deleted a long existing (but small and seldom used) site collection which was at url:

`https://publicsites/mysite`

I then created a new SUB SITE of the root site collection at the same link:

`https://publicsites/mysite`

And the link of the new sub site is broken with 404 and File Not Found errors :/. How can I fix this so that the new site will display at the existing link.

I have verified via DocAve that the new sub site exists and works. I even changed the link and added a '1' at the end of the desired site url and everything works as expected.

Comment: did you reset the IIS?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I did not have to. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer to this question:
[Sharepoint 2010 404 Error after Renaming Subsite](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45408/sharepoint-2010-404-error-after-renaming-subsite)
I was able to fix the error.

Turns out there was a managed path defined in Central Admin for the url I was using that I had to remove.

Comment: Please mark this as your selected answer to put this question in a correct state :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thanks for the reminder. I always forget to come back 2 days later :D

Answer (score 0):

did you reset the IIS? also try to detach and reattach the Content DBs in which your site collection is. Some times orphan stuff stick in the Content DB.